# Prove a limit of a sequence by definiton

Tags: limits

May I ask for helping with proving a limit of a sequence by definiton. I have this assignment.

[image]

And the result should be

[image]

I have already made some calculations, but denominator of the fraction keeps resulting ln(epsilon-1) instead of result. It would mean that this limit does not apply for all of epsilon since it muse be higher than 1 because of logarithm.

Here is my brief calculation

- |(8)^(1/n) - 1 | <= (8)^(1/n) + 1 < epsilon

And then it results in exact result which differs in denominator.

It looks like I have to use the other side of absolute value

- |(8)^(1/n) - 1 | >= (8)^(1/n) - 1

to achieve the result, but why?

Thx a lot

Comment: What is $n_0$?  Please type your questions instead of posting images, so that people using screen readers can read them.  Also, you have to put `$` signs around the MathJax in order for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that exists $n_0$ such that for any $n\ge n_0$

$$\left|\sqrt[n]8 -1 \right|< \epsilon$$

then we have

$$\left|\sqrt[n]8 -1 \right|=\sqrt[n]8 -1< \epsilon\iff \sqrt[n]8<1+\epsilon \iff\log{\sqrt[n]8}=\frac1n\log 8<\log (1+\epsilon)$$

that is

$$n>\frac{\log 8}{\log (1+\epsilon)} \implies n_0=\left[\frac{\log 8}{\log (1+\epsilon)}\right]+1$$

Comment: Sir, how should I deal with that absolute value, you have written that 8^(1/n) - 1 is equal to |8^(1/n) - 1|, should not it be equal or smaller? I dont know how to properly calculate with absolute value.

Comment: We have that  for $a\ge 1$ $\sqrt[n] a \ge 1$.

Comment: Well I understand what you have written but I am afraid I am unable to see explanation. :(

Comment: @naruto25 What is the step which is not clear to you?

Comment: |8^(1/n) - 1| < epsilon    \n

(8^(1/n) - 1) <=  |8^(1/n) - 1| <=  (8^(1/n) + 1) \n     

why do we use (8^(1/n) - 1) and say it is equal to |8^(1/n) - 1| ? ** \n is next line

Comment: @naruto25 As I said, from the definition of limit we need to find $n_0$ such that for any $n\ge n_0$ the following holds $\left|\sqrt[n]8 -1 \right|< \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$. Is it clear so far?

Comment: I totally understand definiton of limit, but I am curious, why |8^(1/n) - 1| = 8^(1/n) - 1 . Is that so because of fact that "1" is smaller, but what if we did have |8^(1/n) - 2|? There must be some work with that absolute value, is not that so?

Comment: @naruto25 In this particular case since $\left|\sqrt[n]8 -1 \right|$ then $\left|\sqrt[n]8 -1 \right|=\sqrt[n]8 -1$. For $\left|\sqrt[n]8 -1 \right|$we can say that $\left|\sqrt[n]8 -2 \right|=\sqrt[n]8 -2 $ only for n=$1$,$2$ and $3$ and $\left|\sqrt[n]8 -2 \right|=2-\sqrt[n]8  $ for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @naruto25 BTW you can use "$...$" to format properly the math text.